# Sync several DATA from Android SQLLite to MariaDB

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, synchronization, mariadb

i look for an easy way to sync my in `SQLLite` stored Data to `MariaDB` SQL Database.

`WebService` is no problem, but i have no clue to get several Data sync at once.

I had an `DBAdapter` with this, the id is store in **sharedpreferences:**

```
 public projekt getprojekt(int id){

    // 2. build projekt query
    Cursor cursor =
            db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_P, // a. table
                    TABLE_P_COLUMNS_ALL, // b. column names
                    " id = ?", // c. selections
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
                    null, // e. group by
                    null, // f. having
                    null, // g. order by
                    null); // h. limit

    // 3. if we got results get the first one
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    // 4. build projekt object
    projekt projekt = new projekt();
    projekt.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    projekt.setKostenstelle(cursor.getString(1));
    projekt.setAG(cursor.getString(2));
    ....

    // 5. return projekt
    return projekt;
}
```

**and this:**

```
// Get Room List
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetRaum(int pid){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> raumList = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE_R + " where pid = '"+ pid +"' order by "+KEY_R_BEZEICHNUNG+" asc";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        HashMap<String,String> raum = new HashMap<>();
        raum.put("id",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_M_ID)));
        raum.put("bezeichnung",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_M_BEZEICHNUNG)));
        raumList.add(raum);
    }
    return  raumList;
}
```

Bit how i get several "Rooms" selected to send it via `POST/JSON` to `WebService`?

My current function to send Data is not finished ... just getting the `projekt_id` from `sharedpreferences`.

```
public void postData() throws JSONException {

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("de.dasal.dguvv3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Integer projektidsp = sharedPreferences.getInt("projekt_id", 0);
    final projekt projekt = db.getprojekt(projektidsp);

}
```

If you need further Informations, please let me know.
Its my first Question on `stackoverflow`.

Comment: Show us a sample of the resulting SQL.